# Where is the Configure function for the Express module in EasyRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, easyrtc

I'm new to NodeJS and maybe I'm putting the cart before the horse here, but I am attempting to run the demo of EasyRTC using NodeJS.

The EasyRTC download page has an "easy install instructions" list of actions to perform to run EasyRTC out of the box.

I encountered a problem with the second to last step - run `server.js` - upon attempting to run it I receive an error claiming that the `httpApp.configure()` function does not exist (`TypeError: undefined is not a function`). Now, `httpApp` is defined as  `require("express");`, so I went over every file within `/node_modules/express/lib` and, as the error suggests, there is no `configure` function defined anywhere...

So, is this just me being a complete n00b and not knowing what I'm doing? I followed all of the steps in their example - and they aren't exactly obtuse instructions.

1. download and install node.js
2. download EasyRTC and place it anywhere you want
3. get EasyRTC dependencies using npm
4. run EasyRTC's server.js

   - (I skipped over the "create folder" and "navigate to folder" steps here because... c'mon)

Am I supposed to manually create the `configure` function for the `express` module? And if so, why do they claim that it runs "out of the box"?

Comment: have you tried the solution which I gave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add that function in express, that function(configure) was removed in express 4.  https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Solution is , go to package.json file , change the json as follow, express from "*" to "3.x" , then run npm install and then run server

```
"dependencies" : {
    "easyrtc"   : "*",
    "express"   : "3.x", 
    "socket.io" : "*"
},
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought to check the release version of the express package